# When using render props in a component, what are some common pitfalls to avoid infinite re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let us say we are implementing protected routes in react using react-router-dom, what are some things we have to keep in mind such as when rendering private route the component does go into an infinite re-rendering loop.

This route is giving me an error of maximum call stack exceeded react prevents infinite rerendering. What is wrong in this component?
PrivateRoute.jsx

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  isAuthenticated,
  token,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const employee = decoder(token);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated && employee.user.emp_role === "admin" ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
  token: state.authReducer.token
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadUser })(PrivateRoute);
```

I'm using mapping to props from redux state, picking necessary parts such as isAuthenticated and token, token is for checking for role which could be admin or employee, putting them in ternary operator and so on. Where is the problem in this component?

EDIT 1:
App.js

```
//imports here
if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Alert />
        <Switch>
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <AdminRoutes exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
              <AdminRoutes exact path="/employees" component={Employees} />
              <AdminRoutes exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
              <AdminRoutes exact path="/chemists" component={Chemists} />
              <AdminRoutes
                exact
                path="/distributors"
                component={Distributors}
              />
              <AdminRoutes exact path="/doctors" component={Doctors} />
              <AdminRoutes exact path="/products" component={Products} />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </Switch>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/representative"
            component={Representative}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.jsx

```
const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated, token }) => {
  const [formData, handleFormData] = useState({
    emp_phone: "",
    emp_password: ""
  });

  const { emp_password, emp_phone } = formData;

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(emp_phone, emp_password);
  };

  const handleLogin = e => {
    handleFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  // if (isAuthenticated) {
  //   const employee = decoder(token);
  //   if (employee.user.emp_role === "admin") {
  //     return <Redirect to="/admin" />;
  //   } else return <Redirect to="/representative" />;
  // }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="w-full max-w-sm shadow-md rounded p-5 m-3 align-middle h-auto">
        <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className="field self-center">
            <label className="label" htmlFor="phone">
              Phone Number
            </label>
            <div className="control">
              <input
                type="text"
                pattern="[0-9]*"
                id="phone"
                placeholder="Enter phone number"
                name="emp_phone"
                required
                value={emp_phone}
                onChange={e => handleLogin(e)}
                className="input"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <label className="label" htmlFor="password">
              Password
            </label>
            <div className="control">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                name="emp_password"
                id="password"
                value={emp_password}
                required
                onChange={e => handleLogin(e)}
                className="input"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="button is-primary">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
  token: state.authReducer.token
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login, loadUser })(Login);
```

Comment: On which route it happens? What is the store state when it happens?

Comment: we go to login page after entering credentials the url is changing based on role let's say admin role and then I'm getting maximum re-renders error; the store state is isAuthenticated true and token from backend

Comment: Can you share your component where you declared Routes?

Comment: spotted a potential source of error in the login page I'm checking isAuthenticated  ( obtained from mapStateToProps) and then based on the role I'm redirecting them to other pages, if I comment it out the error goes away but functionality doesn't work

Comment: Added App.js file where I defined the routes

Comment: Can you share login page too? Does `AdminRoute` involved too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208956/discussion-between-yashwanth-somayajula-and-gadi-tzkhori).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be due to used logic. This happened to me too some weeks ago.

```
isAuthenticated && employee.user.emp_role === "admin" ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    )
```

In above code the value of isAuthenticated when null or false ( during loading from local storage) can be null multiple times which triggers Redirect component multiple times.

Can you try below logic

```
!isAuthenticated && employee.user.emp_role !== "admin" ? (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    ) : (
      <Component {...props} />
    )
```